# Can I swap personal and 401k assets?

Tags: united-states, investing, 401k

Is it possible to swap assets between personal accounts and retirement accounts?

Say I have $100 worth of one fund in my 401k, and I think that fund is better as a short-term investment, and I also have $100 in another fund which I own in a personal account, and I think the second fund would serve well as a long-term investment. To put the asset bought after tax and available to sell at any time into the 401k and pull what's in the pre-tax 401k out would make no net difference in the current value of the retirement account, or are there other obstacles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort of, but not the way you describe it.

You can't just move assets into a 401(k) - you can only contribute cash from your paycheck (unless this "personal account" is another retirement account, e.g. IRA, and your 401(k) accepts rollovers, but I'm assuming you mean a regular taxable account).

Additionally, you can't just move assets out of the 401(k). You could take a distribution, selling the asset and withdrawing the cash, but it would count as taxable income, be subject to a penalty depending on your age, so you would end up with less money than the asset was worth. A distribution may not even be allowed by your plan if you are still employed.

What you **could** do is just exchange the assets (sell one and buy the other) within their current accounts, with two caveats:

- the sale in the taxable account may create a tax liability (if sold for a gain, or a tax deduction if sold for a loss)
- 401(k) plans often have limited investment options available; you may not be able to purchase your desired asset within the plan.

Answer (score 4):

**No**, because

1. you can only contribute to a 401(k) **via payroll deductions**, and
2. 401(k) plans are designed for *long term* investments, not short term investments (unless you're already retired).

It doesn't matter, though, because **money is fungible**.

Thus:

1. within the confines of your 401(k) plan, move that $100 of 401(k) money to a long term investment, and
2. move $100 in the other account to the short term investment.

If your 401(k) options are limited, reduce your 401(k) contribs and put that money into a traditional IRA at a company with a wide variety of investment options.